# Implementation of Bing Spell Check API v7 returns 0 flaggedTokens

Tags: php, api, spell-checking, bing, bing-api

I'm trying to implement the [Bing Spell Check API v7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-spell-check-api-v7-reference). This is my current function:

```
# spell check
function bing_spell_check($q, $lang) {
    $param = array();
    $param['appName'] = PRO_NAME;
    $param['text'] = $q;
    $param['setLang'] = $lang;
    $url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/SpellCheck?'.http_build_query($param);
    $process = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array(
            'Accept: application/ld+json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '.PRO_BING_KEY_SPELL
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($process);
    return $response;
}
```

The problem is that this example:

```
print_r(bing_spell_check('en', 'whts yur name?'));
```

Returns:

```
{  
   "@context":{  
      "@vocab":"http:\/\/bingapis.com\/v7\/schemas\/",
      "s":"http:\/\/schema.org\/",
      "@base":"https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/"
   },
   "@type":"SpellCheck",
   "flaggedTokens":[
   ]
}
```

Which means it has not found any errors. I ran the very same test in [Bing's test tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/), and I received this structure instead:

```
{
  "_type": "SpellCheck",
  "FlaggedTokens": [
    {
      "Offset": 0,
      "Token": "whts",
      "Type": "UnknownToken",
      "Suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "what's",
          "Score": 0.909352914464075
        },
        {
          "suggestion": "whats",
          "Score": 0.810588859407343
        },
        {
          "suggestion": "what is",
          "Score": 0.680176771139565
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Offset": 5,
      "Token": "yur",
      "Type": "UnknownToken",
      "Suggestions": [
        {
          "suggestion": "your",
          "Score": 0.909352914464075
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple, you just mixed up your function parameters. You have

```
function bing_spell_check($q, $lang) {}
```

and

```
bing_spell_check('en', 'whts yur name?');
```

That is where the problem starts, `$q` is now `en` and `$lang` is now `whts yur name?`. Thus when you create your `$param` array you have the language and the text mixed up (which will cause the Spell Check API to silently fail). You can simply fix this by changing the parameter order:

```
function bing_spell_check($lang, $q) {}
```

Now your code

```
<?php
define(PRO_BING_KEY_SPELL, 'XXX');
define(PRO_NAME, 'XXX');

function bing_spell_check($lang, $q) {
    $param = array();
    $param['appName'] = PRO_NAME;
    $param['text'] = $q;
    $param['setLang'] = $lang;
    $url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/spellcheck?'.http_build_query($param);
    $process = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array(
            'Accept: application/ld+json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '.PRO_BING_KEY_SPELL
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($process);
    return $response;
}

print_r(bing_spell_check('en', 'whts yur name?'));
?>
```

results in

```
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "http:\/\/bingapis.com\/v7\/schemas\/",
        "s": "http:\/\/schema.org\/",
        "@base": "https:\/\/api.cognitive.microsoft.com\/api\/v7\/"
    },
    "@type": "SpellCheck",
    "flaggedTokens": [{
        "offset": 0,
        "token": "whts",
        "type": "UnknownToken",
        "suggestions": [{
            "suggestion": "what's",
            "score": 0.909352914464075
        }, {
            "suggestion": "whats",
            "score": 0.810588859407343
        }, {
            "suggestion": "what is",
            "score": 0.680176771139565
        }]
    }, {
        "offset": 5,
        "token": "yur",
        "type": "UnknownToken",
        "suggestions": [{
            "suggestion": "your",
            "score": 0.909352914464075
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can't believe i didn't notice such a dumb error. That's probably the result of programming at 3am hehe. Answer accepted instantly. Thanks!

Comment: @andufo No problem! I am glad I was able to help you.